# Volume of cos(x) using disc method with y-axis

Tags: calculus

I cannot recall how to calculate the volume of $y=\cos(x)$ bounded by $x=-\frac{\pi}{2} , x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ using the disc method around the $y$-axis.

It has been a long time since I have done this. Perhaps someone would help refresh my memory.
Here is what I want to do:

$$V= \pi \int_{0}^1 g(y)^2 dy$$

Is $g(y)= \arccos(y)$? I'm not sure.

Kind regards.

Comment: You should speak in your title of the volume **of revolution** generated when revolving the curve of $y=\cos(x) $ around the y axis.

Comment: Are you sure you want do use disks?  Shells will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the disk method, around the $y$ axis.

$\pi \int_0^1 x^2 dy\\
x = \arccos y\\
\pi \int_0^1 (\arccos y)^2 dy$

Integration by parts:

$u = (\arccos y)^2; dv = dy\\
du = -2\frac {(\arccos y)}{\sqrt {1-y^2}} dy; v = y\\
\pi[y (\arccos y)^2 + \int \frac {2y}{\sqrt {1-y^2}} (\arccos y) dy]\\
y (\arccos y)^2|_0^1 = 0\\
\pi\int \frac {2y}{\sqrt {1-y^2}} (\arccos y) dy$

And parts again.

$u  = \arccos y ; dv = \frac {2y}{\sqrt {1-y^2}} dy\\
du = -\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-y^2}} dy; v = -2\sqrt{1-y^2}\\
\pi[-2\sqrt{1-y^2}\arccos y - \int 2dy]\\\
\pi^2 - 2\pi$

Shells

$2\pi \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} x \cos x \;dx\\
2\pi (x \sin x + \cos x)|_0^{\frac \pi2}\\
2\pi (\frac \pi2 - 1)$